# Diophantine Equations over polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to figure out a set of solutions to an ideal membership problem. Namely, if $f(x,y),g(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ I want to figure out what constraints I need such that they satisfy
$$g(x,y)-2xf(x,y)\in (y-x^2).$$
Since we're in a UFD, and commutative, this is the same as finding a set of solutions $f,g,h \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ to the following equation:
$$g(x,y)-2xf(x,y) = h(x,y)(y-x^2).$$
This looks like a diophantine equation over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ to me and I was wondering if anyone knew any methods to solve problems like this. Thanks.

Comment: This is a one variable problem in the sense that the condition says $g(x,x^2)=2xf(x,x^2)$.